# Does the conductor sometimes play with the soloist (Or on his own)?

Tags: conducting

I watched the following two videos and it gave me the distinct idea that the conductor played something of his own choosing. Does this happen or am I getting my wires crossed?

Malaguena:

Pasacaglia:

Comment: Can anyone maybe tell me how to get those youtube videos embedded?

Comment: Just leave the link raw and the site will do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are times when the conductor will go ahead and be the soloist. It's not that uncommon especially when the orchestra is relatively small.